# google appengine - Time zone changed

Tags: java, date, google-app-engine, timezone

In ServletContextListener initialization method we are setting Time Zone as

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00"));
```

}

But when i check the Time Zone information in servlets and filters the Time Zone got changed.
 Any one know what might be the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe another code location calls `TimeZone.setDefault()`, too.

Comment: No. we are not setting anywhere.

Comment: Please, could you show the source code where the get is called?

Answer (score 1):

See, I've following class

```
public class TimeZ {
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("1."+TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00"));
    System.out.println("2. "+TimeZone.getDefault());
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00"));
    System.out.println("3. "+TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println("4. "+TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00"));    
}
}
```

my output is:

```
1.sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+00:00",offset=0,dstSaving...

2. sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,...

3. sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+00:00",offset=0,dstSaving...

4. sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+00:00",offset=0,dstSaving...
```

> **explanation**: by default my timezone is india. It's going to return the
>   timezone of the JVM TimeZone.getDefault() is executed on. So if the
>   application is running on a server in India, it will be something like
>   "Asia/Calcutta" .when you set default timezone to GMT, it changes its timezone to
>   GMT zone. thats simple...

Comment: Our servers are running in US only. Even we are setting the time zone.

Comment: iam sorry by default  you get a TimeZone using getDefault which creates a TimeZone based on the time zone where the program is running. For example, for a program running in Japan, getDefault creates a TimeZone object based on Japanese Standard Time.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: But in the ServletContextListener we are setting the JVM default time zone  as TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00")). Why its changing?

Comment: because you're setting Gmt time to the default time zone.if  your default time zone is india you're explicitily setting to gmt which is europe i think.  " India's Time Zones were established in 1884. Originally there were two Time Zones, the Bombay Time and Calcutta Time. Bombay continued to have a different time (39 minutes behind IST) until 1955. IST, which is GMT plus 5.30 hrs, came into existence in 1905"

Comment: what time or timezone info  you getting when you settin in to setTimezone....? and what time zone was there before setting?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot address your Question specifically as you do not show us the code for how you *get* time zone. But I can give you some tips.

Your code should be working. The problem is likely to be in (a) how you are getting the time zone or (b) the default zone being set somewhere else.

Add a line of code before and after where you set the zone to get the zone so as to log the change taking effect. See this done in the [Answer by Sheeran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42532946/642706).

Use the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The **default time zone applies to the *entire* JVM**. Any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can change the default at any moment at runtime. Such a change affects all code in all threads of all apps within the JVM. So relying on the JVM’s current default time zone is **risky and ill-advised** in general but especially so on a server and even more so on a Servlet container.

Furthermore, the best practice on servers is to keep the default time zone in UTC. Though, again, you should not rely on that default.

There is almost never a need to set the default. Instead, pass explicitly the desired/expected time zone as a `ZoneId` (or `ZoneOffset`) as the optional argument to the various methods in java.time. Frankly I wish all those zone arguments were required rather than optional as most programmers fail to think about the crucial issue of zones and offsets.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment in UTC.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Much of your work should be done in UTC rather than with zoned values. Programmers should generally be thinking, working, logging, exchanging data, and serializing data all in UTC. As a programmer, you should stop  thinking parochially about your own personal time zone while on the job, as constant conversions in/out of that zone will muddy your thoughts, lead to errors, and drive you crazy. Generally you should assign zones only where expected by your user in presentation in the user-interface.

Comment: In a servlet i am logging like - log.info("Time zone : " + TimeZone.getDefault()); . But we are setting the JVM Time Zone in the ServletContextListner. Why it got changed?